# < c:import url...> doesn't call controller method when redirected from another controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jstl

I've created a jsp view (called "foo" for example), which has 2 < c:import ...>  tags in them to load 2 partial views (called "subFoo1" and "subFoo2" for example).
the way it's done is, I have 3 methods in the controller, one for each view
   fooController - foo, 
   sub1Controller > subFoo1, 
   sub2Controller > subFoo2

When I click on the button that takes me to fooController which returns a ModelAndView (foo.jsp), the other 2 partial views are loaded by the < c:import ...> tags and work 100% fine.

The problem is that, when I call fooController from another controller (so not a request from a browser, but from another controller that has, for example, saved something to the db), then foo.jsp loads fine, but subFoo1 and subFoo2 do not load at all.

Debugging shows that the right parameters are passed to fooController and foo.jsp and that both sub1Controller and sub2Controller are never called.

This leads me to believe that the < c:import ... > tags are not calling their URLs when foo.jsp is rendered by calling its controller from another controller, instead of a request from a browser.

As I've said before, it works 100% when a request is made from the browser to fooController, but not when I call fooController from another controller.

I've searched around, but can't seem to find something quite like this. As I understand it, < c:import ... > swallows the HTML response from the URL and embeds it on the page it's on. I can't understand why it would make a difference how foo.jsp is requested, it should have no impact on the < c:import ...> tags as far as I'm concerned (am I wrong is saying that?)

Comment: I found a work around, but it's not really a fix but it makes it work now : instead of return fooController(id) in the controller, I now redirect so it's like a browser request return new ModelAndView("redirect:/foo/5/");. 

I still wonder why it doesn't work if I just return fooController(5); but alas, at least something is working